# add product link to sku (or product name) in new order mail

Tags: php, email, magento

hy,
i'm trying to add a link to the new order email that the customer is getting when he is placeing a new order in magento (my version 1.6.2.0 )

i have edited /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
with the following:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
----
<!-- Start of edit file -->  
<a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getSku($_item)) ?></a>
```

When i receive the confirmation email in the sku column the color changes form black ( default css ) to light blue link like, but it does not have any link property as shown below:
[email_photo](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-IXDN4Qhpv6o/UP8FusEMVII/AAAAAAAAAB8/pPj_zDzoCAc/s656/link_email.jpg)
I have also tried :

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrlPath($_item) ?>">
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getSku($_item)) ?></a>
```

and i end up with the same thing.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: are you saying it is not going to`<?php echo $this->getUrlPath($_item) ?>`?

Comment: yap that's what i'm saying :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In line

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrlPath($_item) ?>">
```

$this is an instance of block *Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Order_Default*. It does not have a function getUrlPath() or getProductUrl.

You should use your $_item variable to get a product object and then it to get its URL

```
$_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl()
```

Comment: i'll try anything at this time :)

Comment: glad I could help. And you try sleep, if that an option ;)

Answer (score 0):

I earlier tried this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getUrlPath() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getSku($_item)) ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2**

To link a product name with its product page in your order emails, edit following files:

```
Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml
Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml
```

To get the product URL, use the following snippet of code and insert it into a href attribute of the link.

```
<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>
```

For example,

```
<p class="product-name"> <a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()); ?> </a> </p>
```

The result of the snippet of code will be a clickable product name in Magento Emails.

Tutorial from: https://themes.email/magento/product-links-in-magento-order-emails.html